# Can you run multiple Chrome instances with different proxies?

Tags: google-chrome, proxy

I'm trying to run multiple instances of of Chrome with different proxies. Searching the web I've found that chrome supposedly supports 'chrome.exe --proxy-server="proxy:port" ' from the command line. But I've tried that and it doesn't work.

Is there any way to run multiple instances of Chrome with different proxies?

Thanks!

Answer (score 14):

The answer from gengkev is correct. For all users combing from search engines who need a quick "copy and paste" solution, use this link target (windows):

`"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --proxy-server="http://proxy01.your.proxy:3128" --user-data-dir="%LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\Chrome-proxy01\User Data"`

Chrome will create this new folder "Chrome-proxy01" on its own. With this you can have multiple chrome shortcuts using different proxy servers.

Comment: Thank you. How do i do the same with login and password fo rmy proxy? I want to run few instances of chrome with different proxy each.

Answer (score 8):

As mentioned in the previous answer, the way to do that is to:

- Pass a --proxy-server parameter
- Pass a **different** user data directory path for every launch with a different proxy server

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --proxy-server="http://proxy01.your.proxy:3128" --user-data-dir="%LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\Chrome-proxy01\User Data"
```

Where `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\Chrome-proxy01\User Data` folder needs to be unique for any new instance that uses a different proxy. So use `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\Chrome-proxy02\User Data` for the second launch, `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\Chrome-proxy03\User Data` for the third launch etc.

I would also highly advise to use the `--no-first-run` flag to get rid of the annoying popup that asks you whether you want to set chrome as your default browser every time you launch it with a new data directory

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --proxy-server="http://proxy01.your.proxy:3128" --user-data-dir="%LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\Chrome-proxy01\User Data" --no-first-run
```

Comment: Is it possible to point user dir at an existing Profile or I would have to remake them?  I tried this pointing at the existing profile, and with/without `--profile-directory` but it seems like it made a new profile each time.

Answer (score 7):

If you're running more than one instance of chrome with different flags, I think you need to [specify different paths to --user-data-dir](http://www.chromium.org/user-experience/user-data-directory).

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can run it. To do so:

1. Install the extension [SwitchyOmega](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/proxy-switchyomega/padekgcemlokbadohgkifijomclgjgif?hl=en) in the profiles that you want to use proxy.
2. Create a profile with your desired name and enter the details of the proxy that you wish to use.
3. Save the changes using apply changes button.
4. Switch to your proxy using the extension button present on the top right corner of the chrome.

In addition I am also attaching extension screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As of 2014-10-05, the easiest way to run multiple versions or instances of Chrome is to use Google Chrome Portable, downloaded from:
http://portableapps.com/apps/internet/google_chrome_portable

Currently I'm running 4 separate instances of Google Chrome v37.0.2062.124. One instance is installed and three other instances of Google Chrome are portable.

Here's how my Windows 7 Taskbar looks like when all 4 instances of Chrome are opened:
http://image.bayimg.com/a024621496637cbdc2ad85324ed5e8e07b9f5453.jpg

If you want to change Google Chrome icon that is shown on the Windows Taskbar once Google Chrome is started, then you should follow this link:
https://superuser.com/questions/613851/is-it-possible-to-customize-taskbar-icons-if-so-how

The answer is given in comments: you need to change icons that are stored in chrome.dll using Resource Tuner (use Trial version) or Resource Hacker (free).

When you run totally separate instances of **Chrome**, you can make those separate **Chrome** instances use different proxies through **Chrome** settings of that particular instance of **Chrome**.

Comment: how does this use different proxy settings? I have downloaded it at it seems to use the same proxy settings.

Comment: came across [this](http://www.sureshjoshi.com/productivity/managing-multiple-chrome-proxy-profiles/) which might be an option but have not had success with it yet.

Answer (score 2):

You can make multiple "people" (settings > manage other people > add person). You can then open a instance for each person(you don't have to login to google for the other "people"). Then you can configure a proxy for that instance.
To get the menu that's shown in the picture just click on your profile icon on the top right.
[image]